# PHP/MySQL Update query every 2 column update room change automated

Tags: php, mysql

I want to create automated room divisions.

Assumptions :

- I have 4 data.
- Each room maximum 2 people.

If room is full / reach max "2", 3th people automated insert to the next room.

Here my code. assumption 4 data.

```
$kuota=2; //Max 2 data in 1 room

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
$id = $row["id"];
$x=1;
while($x<=$kuota) {
    $sql2 = "UPDATE cds SET room=$y WHERE id='$id'";
    $query2 = mysqli_query($con, $sql2) or die (mysqli_error($con));
    $x++;
}
$y++

}
```

but it doesn't work.

My code is so ugly :(

I want to get a result like this

```
name     ||  Room
Michael  ||   1
Muller   ||   1
...
Cyntia   ||   2
Gina     ||   2
```

Comment: you first have to do a select query to find the next free room

Comment: dagon : can u give me some example?

Answer (score 0):

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $id = $row['id'];
    $sql2 = "UPDATE cds AS c1
             CROSS JOIN (SELECT room
                         FROM cds
                         GROUP BY room
                         HAVING COUNT(*) < $kuota
                         ORDER BY room
                         LIMIT 1) AS c2
             SET c1.room = c2.room
             WHERE id = $id";
    mysqli_query($con, $sql2) or die (mysqli_error($con));
}
```

The `c2` subquery returns the first room that has fewer than `$kuota` people assigned to it.